# Fill a cell based on previous cell entry

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet that has a column with data validation.  That validation refers to another worksheet within the workbook.  The user can select a Control value from that list.  What I’d like to be able to do is have the next column autofill, based on the selection I just made.

**Sheet 1**

| Desc 1 | Desc 2 | Control (selected from (Validation worksheet) | Control Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Blah, blah | Blah, blah, blah | 5.1 | *Fill in title based on control number |
| ----------- | ---------------- | --------------------- | ------------------------------------- |

**Validation Worksheet**

| Control | Control Title (Source) |
| --- | --- |
| 5.1 | Monkey Feet |
| 5.1.1 | Monkey Toes |
| --------- | -------------------- |

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX/MATCH`:

Assumption: you insert on both sheets a table for the data (Insert > table) and name the first one tblData, the second one tblControls
Then put the following formula in your Control Title-Column of tblData:

`=INDEX(tblControls[Control Title (Source)],MATCH([@Control],tblControls[Control],0))`